# Помогите написать регулярное выражение на js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как говорится, если хочешь решить проблему с помощью регулярных выражений, то у тебя две проблемы. Прошу помощи написать регулярку для следующих условий:

В поле для имени менеджера нужно:

- разрешить пробелы, но не в начале и не в конце
- разрешить только буквенные символы (без цифр) на кириллице и латинице
- разрешить символы "',.- (и пробел)

Я попробовал вот такую: /^[^\s]+[\w\s"',.]+[^\s]+$/g
Но по ней не проходит строка меньше трёх символов и не проходит кириллица

Должны проходить следующие значения:

```
Иванов Иван Иванович
Иванов "Ванёк" Иван
Иванов 'Ванёк' Иван
Иванов Вань-Вань Иван
Иванов Ivan
Ivan Ivaнович
Иванов Иван, Петров Петр
Иванов. Петров. Сидоров.
```

Не должны проходить:

```
Ив%н
Иван1
 Ваня  (тут пробел в начале и в конце)
Иванов№!:?*()><?/
```

Comment: Приведите примеры, которые должны находиться, и примеры, которые не должны находиться. Пробелы это именно пробелы или whitespace, как у вас в регулярке? Какая минимальная длина строки?

Comment: @dIm0n обновил вопрос, добавил примеры

Comment: Ответьте ещё на вопросы

Comment: @dIm0n Минимальной длины нет - хоть один символ, хоть 1000. Пробелы и такие и такие

Comment: Так 0 символов может быть или нет?

Comment: @dIm0n да! Ноль символов допустимо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот (хотя бы 1 символ либо пустая строка):

```
(?:^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z"',.-]+(?:\s+[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z"',.-]+)*$)|^$
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/VnNxYh/2

> **Иванов Иван Иванович**
>
> **Иванов "Ванёк" Иван**
>
> **Иванов 'Ванёк' Иван**
>
> **Иванов Вань-Вань Иван**
>
> **Иванов Ivan**
>
> **Ivan Ivaнович**
>
> **Иванов Иван, Петров Петр**
>
> **Иванов. Петров. Сидоров.**
>
> **ffff  fffff**
>
> Ив%н
>
> Иван1
>
> Ваня
>
> Ваня
>
> Ваня
>
> Иванов№!:?*()><?/

Сгенерированный код:

```js
const regex = /(?:^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z"',.-]+(?:\s+[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z"',.-]+)*$)|^$/gm;
const str = `Иванов Иван Иванович
Иванов "Ванёк" Иван
Иванов 'Ванёк' Иван
Иванов Вань-Вань Иван
Иванов Ivan
Ivan Ivaнович
Иванов Иван, Петров Петр
Иванов. Петров. Сидоров.
ffff  fffff

Ив%н
Иван1
 Ваня
Ваня 
 Ваня  
Иванов№!:?*()><?/`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Как указали в других ответах, при наличии опции `i` можно укоротить регулярку, если писать буквы только в одном регистре

Answer (score 2):

```js
var regex = /^(?!\s)((?!\s$)[-A-ZА-ЯЁ"',.\s])*$/i

var yes = [
  "Иванов Иван Иванович",
  'Иванов "Ванёк" Иван',
  "Иванов 'Ванёк' Иван",
  "Иванов Вань-Вань Иван",
  "Иванов Ivan",
  "Ivan Ivaнович",
  "Иванов Иван, Петров Петр",
  "Иванов. Петров. Сидоров.",
]

var no = [
  "Ив%н",
  "Иван1",
  " Ваня ",
  "Иванов№!:?*()><?/",
]

console.log(yes.every(s => regex.test(s)))
console.log(no.every(s => !regex.test(s)))
```

Если есть возможность использовать более новый стандарт js, то можно упростить:

```js
var regex = /^(?!\s)[-A-ZА-ЯЁ"',.\s]*(?<!\s)$/i

var yes = [
  "Иванов Иван Иванович",
  'Иванов "Ванёк" Иван',
  "Иванов 'Ванёк' Иван",
  "Иванов Вань-Вань Иван",
  "Иванов Ivan",
  "Ivan Ivaнович",
  "Иванов Иван, Петров Петр",
  "Иванов. Петров. Сидоров.",
]

var no = [
  "Ив%н",
  "Иван1",
  " Ваня ",
  "Иванов№!:?*()><?/",
]

console.log(yes.every(s => regex.test(s)))
console.log(no.every(s => !regex.test(s)))
```

Чтобы запретить переводы строк:

```js
var regex = /^(?!\s)((?!\n|\s$)[-A-ZА-ЯЁ"',.\s])*$/i

var yes = [
  "Иванов Иван Иванович",
  'Иванов "Ванёк" Иван',
  "Иванов 'Ванёк' Иван",
  "Иванов Вань-Вань Иван",
  "Иванов Ivan",
  "Ivan Ivaнович",
  "Иванов Иван, Петров Петр",
  "Иванов. Петров. Сидоров.",
]

var no = [
  "Ив%н",
  "Иван1",
  " Ваня ",
  "Иванов№!:?*()><?/",
]

console.log(yes.every(s => regex.test(s)))
console.log(no.every(s => !regex.test(s)))
```

Comment: ТС сказал, что любой whitespace, не только пробелы

Comment: Вроде в вопросе только про пробел. Если заменять на `\s`, то скорее всего переводы строк надо выкинуть.

Comment: Посмотрите комментарии. Я там спросил *"Пробелы это именно пробелы или whitespace, как у вас в регулярке?"*. На что он ответил *"Пробелы и такие и такие"*

Comment: @dIm0n, обновил.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
   ^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z"',.-]+(\s+[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z"',.-]+)*$|^$
```

обновил

Comment: ТС уже привёл примеры для тестов

Comment: Да прогоняю сейчас

Comment: По Вашему примеру не проходят: Иванов "Ванёк" Иван

Иванов 'Ванёк' Иван

Comment: @Slavrov проверьте обновил, у меня всё прошло

Comment: Находит одиночный `/`

Comment: Да видел исправляю

Comment: @dIm0n Вроде норм

Comment: @AzizUmarov теперь только пустые строки остались

Comment: @dIm0n Не знаю зачем это но я добавил :)

Answer (score 1):

Примеры ТС проходят.

`/^(?:[^\s\d][a-zа-яё\s"',.-]+[^\s\d])?$/i`

```js
let pattern = new RegExp("^(?:[^\\s\\d][a-zа-яё\\s\\\"',.-]+[^\\s\\d])?$", "i");

console.log(pattern.test("")); //true
console.log(pattern.test("Иванов Иван Иванович")); //true
console.log(pattern.test('Иванов "Ванёк" Иван')); //true
console.log(pattern.test("Иванов 'Ванёк' Иван")); //true
console.log(pattern.test("Иванов Вань-Вань Иван")); //true
console.log(pattern.test("Иванов Ivan")); //true
console.log(pattern.test("Ivan Ivaнович")); //true
console.log(pattern.test("Иванов Иван, Петров Петр")); //true
console.log(pattern.test("Иванов. Петров. Сидоров.")); //true
console.log(pattern.test("Ив%н")); //false
console.log(pattern.test("Иван1")); //false
console.log(pattern.test(" Ваня ")); //false
console.log(pattern.test("Иванов№!:?*()><?/")); //false
```

Comment: Не, одиночный `/` не находило сразу. Где смотрите? Проблема только с пустой строкой.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/48nxCI/1

Comment: Я понял, но это не одиночный это в связке с предыдущей строкой. Короче из-за мультистрок.

Comment: Да, согласен. А как можно без кода js протестировать эту регулярку на разных строках тогда?

Comment: Это вопрос к ТС. Фраза `"Поле для имени менеджера"` говорит мне, что это скорее `input`, чем `textarea`. Фраза во множественном числе `"Должны проходить следующие значения:"` для меня однозначно разные значения, а не одно многострочное. Ваш пример принят ТС, значит проблема в постановке задачи.

Comment: Вы правы. Это input. Мультистрок не будет

Comment: @Slavrov ясно. Добавил поддержку пустой строки, может пригодится кому-нибудь.

Comment: Ну не работает же: `%%`, `Q`.